# Using NMAP to create a client environment report/network model

Tags: networking, scripting, report, nmap, network-scan

I have a question about using NMAP to generate reports for clients. So at work recently I was tasked with creating a quick way to evaluate Client networks and be able to create a document describing their environment.

NMAP seemed to be the go to tool since its open-source and has the ability to scan OSs,Networks,Services,etc, and then output it into a xml or html form.

My question is: If that is anything else I could use to generate a nice topography model with corresponding OS and Services tags, plus hardware, or I would be better off to just write a script myself?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Zenmap, which is the GUI addition to nmap.

-It will create a graph with topology of the network, color code hosts (simple: green is good, red is bad), simple icons.

-if you click on Profile>New Profile>Scripts  you will find useful scripts that will do pen testing etc. each one of those profiles will be saved for future use

Everything(graph & output text) can be saved to file, most importantly the graph can be understood by less technical people.